# Getting first visible iFrame within a window and printing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, telerik, radwindow

Kind of an absurd situation... This is only really only for IE8 and lower.

Anyway I have an iFrame appearing (which I can't control  / create an ID for), appreciate it Telerik!

```
// The only way I can grab it specifically would be:
var iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[id] : document.getElementById(id);
                                             // ^ you grab by ID in IE
var ifWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
```

But since I don't have the ID, I can't use this method...
I've tried a few different methods, with no success.

```
// tried either window. / or document.
document.frames.print();
window.frames.print();
document.frames[0].print();
```

**I basically just want to just, GRAB the first iFrame -> and print it**

**Side note**: `window.print()` works in everything besides IE8 & lower. For IE, it prints only the outer / parent window content, instead of the iFrame that is currently focused on.

Any thoughts?

---

**Update:** So somehow doing `window.frames[2].print()` in the *IE console* works (and grabs the correct frame). When I try to put this code in the Javascript, I have the exact same thing: `window.frames[2].print()`, IE interprets this code into *dot notation* `window.frames.2` and doesn't work and comes back as null or not an object. Typing that same dot notation into the console doesn't work and just gives me "Expected ;" (which makes no sense).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
```

I tested this in an IE8 console and it works (but it may still have the problem in your update).

As for the other part of your question about printing the first **visible** iframe, you probably will want to look at the scrollX and scrollY and the offsetTop and offsetLeft, no?

Answer (score 1):

Most of these old *collections* in javascript has a *method* * called `item`, so try this:

```
window.frames.item(2).print();
```

(*) Do not wonder, `typeof window.frames.item` will be `'object'`.

Comment: Note that this works in IE but not Chrome in 2018. You'd have to use brackets for Chrome.